# Help with Query Tuning

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, query

**EDIT** - drachenstern: see this question for more information on this problem and on the source of his query below:

> [Group data by non-unique keys by distinct time range](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1334/group-data-by-non-unique-keys-by-distinct-time-range)

Can someone please advise some tuning options for the following query? When running for one project it is fast but for all the records it takes hours to finish running. NUM_ROWS in PA table: 2,101,528

I want to group data by non-unique keys by a distinct time range

```
SELECT project_nbr, status, MIN(aud_timestamp) start_dt, end_dt 
FROM (
    SELECT a.project_nbr
         , status
         , aud_timestamp
         , ( SELECT MAX(p.aud_timestamp) 
             FROM pa p 
             WHERE p.project_nbr = a.project_nbr 
               AND p.status = a.status 
               AND p.aud_timestamp >= a.aud_timestamp
               AND NOT EXISTS (
                            SELECT NULL 
                            FROM pa q
                            WHERE q.project_nbr = p.project_nbr 
                              AND q.status <> p.status 
                              AND q.aud_timestamp < p.aud_timestamp 
                              AND q.aud_timestamp > a.aud_timestamp
                               )
            ) end_dt
     FROM pa a
     )
GROUP BY project_nbr, status, end_dt
```

Comment: What database are you using?  What version of that database are you using?  What is the query plan?  What indexes, if any, are available?

Comment: Oracle 11g R2,indexes on project_nbr, status, aud_timestamp    I couldnt paste all the plan since its big..but high level one SELECT STATEMENT  ALL_ROWS Cost: 23,994  Bytes: 10,354,014  Cardinality: 383,482

Comment: @Leigh..please see my question "Group data by non-unique keys by distinct time range" for details.

Comment: @Sree - Why can't you post the query plan?  There are only 3 table references in your query, the plan can't possibly be all that big.  Without the plan, it's going to be very difficult to help you.

Comment: @Justin - Since task was only one time run..I converted this to plsql block,now it runs within 15sec..Thanks for your time..

Comment: @Sree ~ It really helps the next person coming along to know what you did, so if you can post how you solved the problem as an answer to the question and mark it accepted?

Comment: @drachenstern..First thing I deleted about 650000 bad records from this table..I built a loop where I read this table order by project_nbr,aud_timestamp and every time status or project number changes I log the record into a table..

Answer (score 7):

This is the offending code causing your query to take hours to return results:

```
           and not exists (
                        select null 
                        from pa q
                        where q.PROJect_NBR = p.project_nbr 
                          and q.status <> p.status 
                          and q.aud_timestamp < p.aud_timestamp 
                          and q.aud_timestamp > a.aud_timestamp
                           )
```

You should really convert that to a join instead, because as it stands you are generating a new lookup for each record in the 2million source rows.

Comment: NOTE: this is not gauranteed to be the ONLY cause, but this is a predominant cause. We still want to see the EXPLAIN and any indexes you've got setup. By using a temptable and some indexes we might could do more if you can't alter the underlying tables to add indexes.

Comment: I agree with that, joins can be better performing, then doing exists or in statements.